# SlidingMenu import error

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm trying to import SlidingMenu into my own project, so I download source code from [SlidingMenu Library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) and import it as an android library project, also called SlidingMenu as project name.

After that, so many error comes with, and I did something to try to fix it :

- Change its android:minSdkVersion to 10
- Set ActionBarSherlock & android-support-v13 as SlidingMenu's library
- Clean and rebuild whole SlidingMenu project

And still many error there...

How do I fix this ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:
android:minSdkVersion 7 with SlidingMenu

And from Project Properties -> Android -> Select Android 4.2 as target. hope this helps.

Comment: WOW! it works. Thank you Chronos. You saved my new year holiday :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify targetApi in your manifest?

Comment: I set 16 (android 4.1) at first, now is 17 (android 4.2), and it works.